# Using Index with MATCH

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am using an Excel file with 3 columns.

```
ColumnA (All customers)     ColumnB (E-mail)     ColumnC (Specific customers)

CustNO                      MailAddress          CustNO
1                           test@test.com        5
2                           test2@test2.com      3
```

I want to check if a value in `ColumnA` exists in `ColumnC`, then return the MailAddress on that row from `ColumnB`.

I don't want to check on the exact row, so CustNO 1 in `ColumnA` can appear on row 125 and 230 and 312 in `ColumnC`, with different mail addresses.

From another SO question I have tried:

```
=INDEX(B:B;MATCH(C2;A:A;0))
```

But it keeps giving me the error: `#N/A`

How can i accomplish this? I am using Excel 2013.

EDIT: Retyping the Customer Numbers and editing the function as suggested by CallumDA gives me results.

The problem I have now, if the Customer Number is appearing multiple times in Column C, only the value of the first match is returned, while I need the value of all matches of the same customer number.

Comment: First question is are the CustNo in the columns identical? no extra spaces etc...

Comment: Yes, they are both identical. It is an exact match.

Comment: @MarkVan : could you try my suggestion and let me know if it worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
=INDEX(B:B;MATCH(A2;C:C;0))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it also returns #N/A

Comment: Do you have a `1` in column `C`?

Comment: The customer number is a number of 5 digits, some does start with 1, or contain 1. There is no customer number with just: 1

Comment: `MATCH(A2;C:C;0)` searches column `C` for the exact customer number in `A1`. Will it find anything?

Comment: It didn't in the beginning, while clicking in the cell I saw no difference, no space, etc. I have retyped the exact same number, and now it gives an matching value. Also the =INDEX function as you suggesting is working now.

The problem i have now, if the Customer Number is appearing multiple times in Column C, only the value of the first match is returned, while i need the value of all matches of the same customer number.

Comment: Hi @MarkVan, that's quite a different question and will require a significantly different answer. I suggest you check if your new question has an answer on this site/ Google already, and if not, start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
=INDEX(VALUE(B:B);MATCH(VALUE(C2);VALUE(A:A);0))
```

Comment: This gives me #N/A again, while the other function does gives me results.

Comment: @MarkVan : Thx for letting me know! ;)